# Determine the number of ordered pairs of prime numbers (p, q) such that N = p^2+q^3 is such that each digit from 0 to 9 appears exactly once

Tags: algorithm, math, primes, combinatorics, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have to write a program such that can determine the number of ordered pairs of prime numbers (p, q) such that when N = p^2+q^3 is written in decimal, each digit from 0 to 9 appears exactly once (without leading zeroes).

I thought of using a variation of a sieve of Eratosthenes as it's explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/), however it's also mentioned that a sieve only works for numbers N such that N is less than ten million but by the statement of the problem each N is at least one hundred millions from the fact that each digit appears exactly once and there's no leading zeroes, but I don't have any other ideas apart from this one so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You only need to check primes up to sqrt(9876543210) ≈100,000.

Comment: Re “a sieve only works for numbers N such that N is less than ten million but by the statement of the problem each N is at least one hundred millions”: The N in your problem is not the same n as the n in the web page about the sieve you link to. Also, that web page does not save a sieve will not work for n above ten million; it just alleges the sieve is “one of the most efficient” ways to find primes when n is smaller than ten million. The N in your problem is p^2+q^3. The n in the sieve would be the p in your problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike No, consider the smallest value of p to find the upper bound for q and vice versa : q <= cbrt(9876543210 - 2^2) and p <= sqrt(9876543210 - 2^3). So we need to check primes up to sqrt(9876543210 - 2^3).

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the fact that the largest prime you can cube and still form a potentially valid number is 2143.

Ruby code (read as pseudocode if you don't use Ruby):

```rb
require 'prime'
    
def f()
  # Determine the max & min numbers that can be made with 10 distinct digits and no leading zeroes
  max_num = 9_876_543_210
  min_num = 1_023_456_789
  
  # Find the largest prime having a cube <= max_num
  max_prime_to_cube = 2143
  
  count = 0
  
  # Cube every prime up to 2143 
  Prime.each do |prime_to_cube|
    return count if prime_to_cube > max_prime_to_cube
    cubed_val = prime_to_cube ** 3
    
    # Try adding the square of every prime until we exceed the maximum valid number
    Prime.each do |prime_to_square|
      squared_val = prime_to_square ** 2
      combined_val = squared_val + cubed_val
      next if combined_val < min_num
      break if combined_val > max_num
      
      # Check if all digits are unique
      if has_each_digit_once(combined_val)
        count += 1
        puts "val: #{combined_val} = #{prime_to_square}^2 + #{prime_to_cube}^3, count: #{count}"
      end
    end
  end
end


# Check each digit, setting bits of check_int where the i'th bit represents digit i
def has_each_digit_once(val_to_check)
  check_int = 0
  10.times do
    check_bit = 1 << (val_to_check % 10)
    
    # Exit early if we see a digit for the second time
    return false if check_bit & check_int > 0
    
    check_int |= check_bit
    val_to_check /= 10
  end
  return check_int == 1023
end
```

Results:

```
> f
val: 1328675409 = 36451^2 + 2^3, count: 1
val: 1478325609 = 38449^2 + 2^3, count: 2
val: 3085469217 = 55547^2 + 2^3, count: 3
val: 3507126849 = 59221^2 + 2^3, count: 4
...
val: 9682357410 = 5689^2 + 2129^3, count: 1267
val: 9837162450 = 13681^2 + 2129^3, count: 1268
val: 9814362750 = 523^2 + 2141^3, count: 1269
val: 9815674302 = 1259^2 + 2141^3, count: 1270
=> 1270
```

Comment: This could be more efficient by maintaining an array of primes and starting the squared_prime inner loop with the smallest possible prime instead of always starting with 2.

Comment: this looks fine but you aren't counting pairs such that p^2 > 2143 and p^3 is less than that but is a valid pair, or what am i missing?

Comment: @H4z3 2143 is the largest prime that can be cubed and still not exceed 9876543210. We check every prime from 2 up to 2143 to be our cubed prime. Let's say p is some particular cubed prime in that range. Then let's call our other prime q. We know that 1023456789 <= p^3 + q^2 <= 9876543210, so for a given p, we can calculate the range of possible q^2, and taking the square root of both endpoints gives us the range of possible q.

Comment: @H4z3 As you can see in the results I posted, the one 2 up from the bottom is val: 9837162450 = 13681^2 + 2129^3, count: 1268. Here we have the prime being squared as 13,681 and the prime being cubed as 2,129 < 2,143.

Comment: @H4z3 I refactored the code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same technique as @Dave, but with a variable initial value for the inner loop, we get about 20% less iterations. I think this would be the optimal way. Here is an example using php, with access to 2 functions: `p()` is the nth prime and `pi()` is the prime counting function.

```
$nbr = 0;
$min = 1023456789;
$max = 9876543210;

for($i = 1; $i <= pi(floor(sqrt($max-2**3))); $i++){
    $p = p($i);
    for($j = pi(floor(max([0,$min-p($i)**2])**(1/3)))+1; $j <= pi(floor(($max-p($i)**2)**(1/3))); $j++){ 
        $q = p($j);
        $n = $p**2+$q**3;

        $arr = str_split($n);
        sort($arr);
        if(join("", $arr) === '0123456789'){
            $nbr++;
        }
    }
}

echo $nbr;
```

Output:

```
1270
```

Note: the `max()` function is to avoid errors with cubic root of negative numbers.